# Extra whitespace around div HTML CSS

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am building up a sample webpage using HTML and CSS. I am also using Bootstrap. I noticed a difference in the output of the page before linking Bootstrap CSS and after linking Bootstrap CSS.
Below is my code and output:

*Before adding Bootstrap*
[image]

*After adding Bootstrap*
[image]
Before adding Bootstrap, the menu bar seems to come out of the margins, but after adding Bootstrap, the menu bar sticks to the margins clearly. Why is this happening? What property in Bootstrap makes this change happen?

Below is my code:
**index.html :**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-us">
<head>
<title>Server App</title>
<link href='style.css' rel='stylesheet' />
</head>
<body>
<div id='top-bar' class="menu">
    <div id="logo">
    <img src="images/logo.png" width="220px" />
    </div>
    <ul>
    <li class="pill active">Home</li>
    <li class="pill">About Us</li>
    <li class="pill">Photos</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div id = "content">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**style.css:**

```
body{
    background-color:#C6C4C4;
}
#top-bar{
    position:relative;
    background-color:#6A5293;
    padding:0px 0px 0px 0px;
    height:50px;
    margin:0px 0px 0px 0px;
    width:100%;
    display:block;
}
.menu ul{
    list-style-type:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    float:right;
}
.menu li{
    float:left;
}
.pill{
    display:flex !important;
    width: 120px;
    height:50px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    background-color:#6A5290;
    justify-content:center;
    align-items:center;
    padding: 4px;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
.pill:hover{
    background-color:#5d3f91;
}
.active{
    background-color:#5d3f91;
}
#logo{
    float:left;
}
#content{
    height:800px;
    width:70%;
    margin-right:auto;
    margin-left:auto;
    background-color:#fff!important;
    margin-top:10px;
    margin-bottom:10px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There's a CSS reset in Bootstrap that sets margins to 0.

Comment: Also used can be `* {margin;0px;}` as this will clear the margin for every element, if your wishing to start with your own css